# Should workplace related questions involving communication be on-topic?

Tags: discussion

Proper communication is an important aspect in life at workplace. However, **should workplace related questions like *how do I approach someone for promotion* etc be on-topic?**

We have [Workplace SE](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/) for all questions related to the workplace. So which kind of workplace questions can be on-topic here?

Comment: Try it, with a full body to go along with the title, and then we'll be better able to judge whether we think it fits the site topic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Specific to the sample, if the question is focused on developing the interpersonal skills needed to make the request, I think it would be better here than on Workplace. OTOH if it's about the how to do it (when, what setting, etc.) it seems like Workplace is a better option.

In a more general vein, questions about improving, or correcting, interpersonal skills ought to be on-topic here. Such questions should also be answered in light of the interpersonal skills involved, leaving "workplace" elements out of the answer. Interpersonal skills impact every element of our lives, and they should be safe to raise here, no matter what part of life they involve. The key will be keeping the answers focused on the interpersonal aspects, and not becoming sidetracked into the other elements of the situation.

Answer (score 2):

### Yes, but not the example you used

We should only be addressing situations that arise in a workplace, not questions specific to a workplace on how to achieve a goal (like the example, which should go into the work se). If he wanted to know about how to talk to his boss outside of work, or how to behave in a general chat with him inside work, that would be okay.

We shouldn't be giving advice on how people should behave in the workplace in terms of their jobs or how to deal with their bosses problems with them, but we should deal with personal issues they're having when interacting with a set person/people.

We don't want to take any more than the bare minimum of questions from another site.

Essentially the questions should be about a situation that you would normally face (such as a party or talking to someone) the only difference is that the environment is work. You should be able to take the question out of that environment and have it as a general question which is not obviously work-based.

Comment: So, a question should be on-topic if it involves communication part or there is more?

Comment: @AJ it should only involve communication, and even then not all of it. Anything else that this site isn't for can always also be asked over on the work SE